# jquery mobile change page back issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, back

I has three page in my jquery mobile apps. For example page1.html->page2.html ->page3.html . I navigate to each other page by using mobile change

Here is the example code

```
   $.mobile.changePage("contact-listing.html",

              {
                  allowSamePageTransition: false,
                  transition: 'none',
                  showLoadMsg: false,
                  reverse: true,
              }
```

This work very nice when page1->page2->page3 . but the problem cum when page3->page2 . All javascript function inside page2 is not able to work. Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: are you using multi page (1 HTML with several pages) or multi HTML (several HTML files) template?

Comment: ya i am using multi html

Comment: is your javascript initialized from HEAD?